# How do i make a list of items that takes data from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have an HTML/CSS "contentbox"(It's basically a box that includes an image, title, description, name, etc of a product or item) and i have a database table with all this information for a lot of items/products.
I want to take all this data from product1(title, image, description) from the database and put it in my contentbox.
And i want to do this with all my products from my table and display all this contentboxes below each other. Sort of like the craigslist for sale ads that are in a list.
How do i do this? do i need javascript or where do i start? I don't know much about programming and i'm learning as i go.

I realize i should put some code in my questions so here goes another question:
I have a div container that looks like this:

```
<div class="contentBox">
                <div id="column1">
                    <img src="images/gallery/girlthinking.jpg" alt="" id="imagen">
                </div>

                <div id="column2">
                    <p class="tituloanuncio"><b>Titulo del anuncio</b></p>
                    <p class="descripcionanuncio">Descripcion kfewoijfew</p>
                </div>

                <div id="column3">
                    <p class="precioanuncio"><b>$1000</b></p>
                    <p class="contactoanuncio"><b>Contacto<br></b>Dueño: Alejandro<br>Telefono: 8331578460<br>jorgegilcavazos@gmail.com<br>Facebook</p>
                </div>
</div>
```

It works in html, i want to replace the default values a put in there with data from my table, for example where it says.

```
<div id="column2">
                    <p class="tituloanuncio"><b>Titulo del anuncio</b></p>
                    <p class="descripcionanuncio">Descripcion kfewoijfew/p>
 </div>
```

I would like to replace "titulo del anuncio" with the column 'anuncio_titulo' and replace "descripcion kfewoijfew" with the column 'anuncio_descripcion'.

I have this php code that displays all data from the 2 previus columns i mencioned

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM anuncio");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['anuncio_titulo'];
echo $row['anuncio_descripcion'];
}
```

How do i echo my initial html div container replacing the default text i put with the new columns?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You select, fetch, then echo. Do read up on PHP/SQL tutorials, they are there to help. So are we, when it comes to code problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first fetch the data from database (read about MySQL, [`mysqli` PHP function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)). Then you need to pass the data to the site that user sees using PHP (read about [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/)). Finally you need to display the data with [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/DEFAULT.asp) (read about [HTML with PHP](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/php_with_html.htm)).

Nice explanation of mysqli functions is [here](http://codular.com/php-mysqli). To fetch data:

1. Connect
2. Create query
3. Execute query
4. Get data from query

First connect:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');

// check if connection succeeded
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

Then create and execute query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `live` = 1"

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
```

and get data from query

```
$usernames = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $usernames[] = $row['username'] . '<br />';
}
```

Once you have an array, pass it to your view and print, for example as a part of a table:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($username in $usernames): ?>
    <tr><td><?php $username ?> </td></tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

If you do not need to change data without reloading the page, you don't need javascript or ajax. I can see several ways you can do what you intend to, but will just explain the easiest one.

First is to assign the text to the variable and print it. If it needs to be changed with data from databse then just assign the value to that variable.

```
<?php 
   $title = "Titulo del anucio";
   $desc = "Descripcion kfewoijfew";

   // it has default values, let's say you want to fill them with data from db now
   if(/* some condition here, like data from GET : $_GET['change_data'] == true or something */) {
       $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');
       // (...) and so on like I wrote above, query the data and assign to value
       $res = $result->fetch_assoc() // if you know there is one result you can shorten it
       $desc = $res['anuncio_descripcion'];
       $title = $res['anuncio_titulo'];
   }
?>
               

<div id="column2">
                <p class="tituloanuncio"><b><?php echo $title;?></b></p>
                <p class="descripcionanuncio"><?php echo $desc?>/p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Oh come come now. This has already been said in [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812757/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-items-that-takes-data-from-a-mysql-database#comment36632130_23812757). Give the OP some code samples, at the very least.

Comment: Well that's the answer to the question. Feel free to post your answer and I can remove mine if you wish. I intend to add that after some time so he can read about it a bit first.

Comment: *"Feel free to post your answer"* -- I have, which is a comment and are just as effective. Mind you, nobody downvoted this so let's see if the OP agrees also.

Comment: I updated the answer. As for comments, I've always felt they are to be used for asking for more data concerning the question, suggesting additional information in answers or describing why the answer is wrong, not to provide answers to someone's problems. Am I wrong?

Comment: +1 Very good. It's always best to do so, especially when a person has next to no knowledge on coding as the OP states in the question. Now the OP accepted your answer ;-) cheers

Comment: Sorry anyway, didn't mean to plagiarize your input or something.

Comment: Not a problem, and no offense taken ;-)

Comment: I added code to my original question, thanks for the quick guide.

Comment: What sort of condition should be put into the if statement?

Comment: When do you want to replace it?

Comment: If you always want to replace it on page load, then you can remove this if and instead check if result of a query is not empty, and replace it only then, otherwise leave the default values.